# How to build some components of android build-tools from sources?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, repo

I need to build some components from build-tools from sources.

I need to build `build-tools/25.0.3/lib/dx.jar`.

I found the source file what exactly I need (I hope this is it): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_2.3.0/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/multidex/MainDexListBuilder.java

But how to build this component?

I tried to fetch this git repo, but it's not enough:

```
$ gradle tasks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/tse/a/basegit/base/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'base'.
> Plugin with id 'sdk-files' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.611 secs
```

Could somebody tell the correct sequence of steps?
Is there any developer's instruction, article?